# Sed: Replace N first occurrences of a character

Tags: sed, solaris

I am looking to replace the 5 first occurences of the whitespace character per line inside a sed script. Here's what I have so far

`sed -e "s/ /;/" -e "s/ /;/" -e "s/ /;/" -e "s/ /;/" -e "s/ /;/" myfile`

Is there any nicer way of doing it?

For the record, I am using the Solaris sed. I don't know if it makes any difference.

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean the first *n* occurrences **per line** or the first *n* occurrences in the **entire file**?  I think everyone is assuming the former based on your example, and in that case I'd probably go with [fred's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/sed-replace-n-first-occurrences-of-a-character/21189#21189).

Comment: I meant per line. I assumed it was obvious. I'm edited my question so that it would be clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

reading your question I've remembered that at least GNU Sed (probably not the one you have in Solaris) has the [opposite feature that you want](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html):

> g: Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the
>   first.
>
> number: Only replace the numberth match of the regexp.
>
> ```
> Note: the posix standard does not specify what should happen when
> ```
>
> you mix the g and number modifiers, and currently there is no widely
>   agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the
>   interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the numberth, and
>   then match and replace all matches from the numberth on.

So instead of:

```
hmontoliu@ulises:/tmp/wb$ echo one two three four five six seven | sed 's/ /;/g5' 
one two three four five;six;seven
```

you can get a more terse command to achieve what you want by doing:

```
hmontoliu@ulises:/tmp/wb$ echo one two three four five six seven | sed -e 's/ /;/g' -e 's/;/ /6g'
one;two;three;four;five;six seven
```

Tell us if the Solaris implementation has that feautre.

HTH

Comment: Yes it does work. I like the ingenuity of the answer. However it feels a little hackish, that final `g6` may not be clear to everyone, not to mention that the behavior would be unpredictable on other versions of sed.

Comment: Using ';' is risky when dealing with unknown data, eg. `"seven;7"`. A value of `\x00` would be a safer choice. I don't know if all `sed`s handle `\x00`, but they should at least handle `\x01`... they are both very unliklely to be in normal text data.

Answer (score 5):

It will be easier to keep to your basic idea, than to do some itterative sed juggling.  Maybe a simple for-loop to build the pattern will make it easier to work with.

```
pat=; for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)) ;do pat="$pat s/ /;/;"; done
sed -e "$pat" myfile
```

or just dispense with the multiple `-e` expression options, and just group them all with the `;` expression seperator.

```
sed -e "s/ /;/; s/ /;/; s/ /;/; s/ /;/; s/ /;/" myfile
```

Here is the sed-*only* version, that you typically probably won't bother with, but which does allow you to specify any number of replacements. (via the `{5}`) ...

```
sed -nre ':check;G;/^.*\nx{5}$/{b print};s/^(.*)\n.*$/\1/;s/ /;/;t inc-tally;:print;P;x;s/.*//;x;b;:inc-tally;x;s/(.*)/\1x/;x;b check' myfile
```

The above *one-liner(?)* is a bit scary, so here it is as structured code, to be called via a sed-script file: `sed -nrf "$fsed" myfile`

```
:check             ## check the tally
 G                 ## pattern+=nl+hold
 /^.*\nx{5}$/{     ## we have the full complement of replacements
     b print       ## branch to print (and continue)
 }                 ##      
 s/^(.*)\n.*$/\1/  ##
 s/ /;/            ## change one space (if one is present) 
 t inc-tally       ## branch_on_substitute
:print             ## no more spaces to change
 P                 ## pattern_first_line_print
 x;s/.*//;x        ## kill the accumulated tally chars in hold   
 b                 ## branch to end of proc (continue)
:inc-tally         ##      
 x                 ## swap_pattern_and_hold
 s/(.*)/\1x/       ##
 x                 ## swap_pattern_and_hold
 b check           ## branch_unconditional
```