# Sed -- Replace first k instances of a word in the file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to replace only the first `k` instances of a word.

How can I do this?

Eg. Say file `foo.txt` contains 100 instances occurrences of word 'linux' .

I need to replace first 50 occurrences only.

Comment: You can refer to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/sed-replace-n-first-occurrences-of-a-character

Comment: Do you need sed specifically, or are other tools acceptable? Do you need to work on command line, or is a text editor acceptable?

Comment: Anything that works on command line is acceptable.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The first section belows describes using `sed` to change the first k-occurrences on a line.  The second section extends this approach to change only the first k-occurrences in a file, regardless of what line they appear on.

### Line-oriented solution

With standard sed, there is a command to replace the k-th occurrance of a word on a line.  If `k` is 3, for example:

```
sed 's/old/new/3'
```

Or, one can replace all occurrences with:

```
sed 's/old/new/g'
```

Neither of these is what you want.

GNU `sed` offers an extension that will change the k-th occurrance and all after that.  If k is 3, for example:

```
sed 's/old/new/g3'
```

These can be combined to do what you want.  To change the first 3 occurrences:

```
$ echo old old old old old | sed -E 's/\<old\>/\n/g4; s/\<old\>/new/g; s/\n/old/g'
new new new old old
```

where `\n` is useful here because we can be sure that it never occurs on a line.

#### Explanation:

We use three `sed` substitution commands:

- `s/\<old\>/\n/g4`

  This the GNU extension to replace the fourth and all subsequent occurrences of `old` with `\n`.

  The extended regex feature `\<` is used to match the beginning of a word and `\>` to match the end of a word.  This assures that only complete words are matched.  Extended regex requires the `-E` option to `sed`.
- `s/\<old\>/new/g`

  Only the first three occurrences of `old` remain and this replaces them all with `new`.
- `s/\n/old/g`

  The fourth and all remaining occurrences of `old` were replaced with `\n` in the first step.  This returns them back to their original state.

#### Non-GNU solution

If GNU sed is not available and you want to change the first 3 occurrences of `old` to `new`, then use three `s` commands:

```
$ echo old old old old old | sed -E -e 's/\<old\>/new/' -e 's/\<old\>/new/' -e 's/\<old\>/new/'
new new new old old
```

This works well when `k` is a small number but scales poorly to large `k`.

Since some non-GNU seds do not support combining commands with semicolons, each command here is introduced with its own `-e` option.  It may also be necessary to verify that your `sed` supports the word boundary symbols, `\<` and `\>`.

### File-oriented solution

We can tell sed to read the whole file in and then perform the substitutions.  For example, to replace the first three occurrences of `old` using a BSD-style sed:

```
sed -E -e 'H;1h;$!d;x' -e 's/\<old\>/new/' -e 's/\<old\>/new/' -e 's/\<old\>/new/'
```

The sed commands `H;1h;$!d;x` read the whole file in.

Because the above does not use any GNU extension, it should work on BSD (OSX) sed.  Note, thought, that this approach requires a `sed` that can handle long lines. GNU `sed` should be fine.  Those using a non-GNU version of `sed` should test its ability to handle long lines.

With a GNU sed, we can further use the `g` trick described above, but with `\n` replaced with `\x00`, to replace the first three occurrences:

```
sed -E -e 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/\<old\>/\x00/g4; s/\<old\>/new/g; s/\x00/old/g'
```

This approach scales well as `k` becomes large.  This assumes, though, that `\x00` is not in your original string.  Since it is impossible to put the character `\x00` in a bash string, this is usually a safe assumption.

Comment: This only works for lines and will change the first 4 occurences in every line

Comment: @mikeserv Excellent idea!  Answer updated.

Comment: (1) You mention GNU and non-GNU sed, and suggest `tr '\n' '|' < input_file | sed …`. But, of course, that converts the entire input to one line, and some non-GNU seds cannot handle arbitrarily long lines. (2) You say, “… above, the quoted string `'|'` should be replaced by any character, or string of characters, …” But you cannot use `tr` to replace a character with a string (of length > 1). (3) In your last example, you say `-e 's/\<old\>/new/' -e 's/\<old\>/w/' | tr '\000' '\n'\>/new`. This seems to be a typo for `-e 's/\<old\>/new/' -e 's/\<old\>/new/' -e 's/\<old\>/new/' | tr '\000' '\n'`.

Comment: @G-Man Thanks much!  I've updated the answer.

Comment: this is so ugly

Comment: first few examples don't work on sed/arch `sed (GNU sed) 4.8````$ sed 's/Acme/NotAcme/g4' test
1 Acme
2 Acme
3 Acme
FOO
4 Acme
5 Acme
6 Acme
BAR
7 Acme
8 Acme```

Comment: @chovy That's curious. I just ran the examples again using (GNU sed) 4.7 and they still work for me.  Also, I ran your example (which I interpreted to be `echo 'test 1 Acme 2 Acme 3 Acme FOO 4 Acme 5 Acme 6 Acme BAR 7 Acme 8 Acme' | sed 's/Acme/NotAcme/g4'`) and it correctly returned `test 1 Acme 2 Acme 3 Acme FOO 4 NotAcme 5 NotAcme 6 NotAcme BAR 7 NotAcme 8 NotAcme`

Answer (score 10):

### Using Awk

The awk commands can be used to replace the first N occurrences of the word with the replacement.
The commands will only replace if the word is a complete match.

In the examples below, I am replacing the first `27` occurrences of `old` with `new`

**Using sub**

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(x<27&&$i=="old"){x++;sub("old","new",$i)}}}1' file
```

> This command loops through each field until it matches `old`, it checks the counter is below 27, increments and the substitutes the first match on the line. Then moves onto the next field/line and repeats.

**Replacing the field manually**

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(x<27&&$i=="old"&&$i="new")x++}1' file
```

> Similar to the command before but as it already has a marker on which field it is up to `($i)`, it simply changes the value of the field from `old` to `new`.

**Performing a check before**

```
awk '/old/&&x<27{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(x<27&&$i=="old"&&$i="new")x++}1' file
```

> Checking that the line contains old and the counter is below 27 `SHOULD` provide a small speed boost as it won't process lines when these are false.

**RESULTS**

E.g

```
old bold old old old
old old nold old old
old old old gold old
old gold gold old old
old old old man old old
old old old old dog old
old old old old say old
old old old old blah old
```

to

```
new bold new new new
new new nold new new
new new new gold new
new gold gold new new
new new new man new new
new new new new dog new
new new old old say old
old old old old blah old
```

Comment: The first one (using sub) does the wrong thing if the *string “old” precedes the *word* old; e.g., “Give some gold to the old man.” → “Give some gnew to the old man.”

Comment: @G-Man Yeah i forgot the `$i` bit, its been edited, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Say you want to replace only the first three instances of a string...

```
seq 11 100 311 | 
sed -e 's/1/\
&/g'              \ #s/match string/\nmatch string/globally 
-e :t             \ #define label t
-e '/\n/{ x'      \ #newlines must match - exchange hold and pattern spaces
-e '/.\{3\}/!{'   \ #if not 3 characters in hold space do
-e     's/$/./'   \ #add a new char to hold space
-e      x         \ #exchange hold/pattern spaces again
-e     's/\n1/2/' \ #replace first occurring '\n1' string w/ '2' string
-e     'b t'      \ #branch back to label t
-e '};x'          \ #end match function; exchange hold/pattern spaces
-e '};s/\n//g'      #end match function; remove all newline characters
```

*note: the above will likely not work with embedded comments*
...or in my example case, of a '1'...

#### OUTPUT:

```
22
211
211
311
```

There I use two notable techniques. In the first place every occurrence of `1` on a line is replaced with `\n1`. In this way, as I do the recursive replacements next, I can be sure not to replace the occurrence twice *if* my replacement string contains my replace string. For example, if I replace `he` with `hey` it will still work.

I do this like:

```
s/1/\
&/g
```

Secondly, I am counting the replacements by adding a character to `h`old space for each occurrence. Once I reach three no more occur. If you apply this to your data and change the `\{3\}` to the total replacements you desire and the `/\n1/` addresses to whatever you mean to replace, you should replace only as many as you wish.

I only did all of the `-e` stuff for readability. POSIXly It could be written like this:

```
nl='
'; sed "s/1/\\$nl&/g;:t${nl}/\n/{x;/.\{3\}/!{${nl}s/$/./;x;s/\n1/2/;bt$nl};x$nl};s/\n//g"
```

And w/ GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/1/\n&/g;:t;/\n/{x;/.\{3\}/!{s/$/./;x;s/\n1/2/;bt};x};s/\n//g'
```

Remember also that `sed` is line-oriented - it does not read in the entire file and then attempt to loop back over it as is often the case in other editors. `sed` is simple and efficient. That said, it is often convenient to do something like the following:

Here is a little shell function that bundles it up into a simply executed command:

```
firstn() { sed "s/$2/\
&/g;:t 
    /\n/{x
        /.\{$(($1))"',\}/!{
            s/$/./; x; s/\n'"$2/$3"'/
            b t
        };x
};s/\n//g'; }
```

So with that I can do:

```
seq 11 100 311 | firstn 7 1 5
```

...and get...

```
55
555
255
311
```

...or...

```
seq 10 1 25 | firstn 6 '\(.\)\([1-5]\)' '\15\2'
```

...to get...

```
10
151
152
153
154
155
16
17
18
19
20
251
22
23
24
25
```

...or, to match your example *(on a smaller order of magnitude)*:

```
yes linux | head -n 10 | firstn 5 linux 'linux is an os kernel'
linux is an os kernel
linux is an os kernel
linux is an os kernel
linux is an os kernel
linux is an os kernel
linux
linux
linux
linux
linux
```

Answer (score 5):

A short alternative in Perl:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$n=3} 1 while s/old/new/ && ++$i < $n' your_file
```

Change the value of `$n$ to your liking.

**How it works:**

- For every line, it keeps trying to substitute `new` for `old` (`s/old/new/`) and whenever it can, it increments the variable `$i` (`++$i`).
- It keeps working on the line (`1 while ...`) as long as it has made less than `$n` substitutions in total and it can make at least one substitution on that line.

Answer (score 4):

Use a shell loop and `ex`!

```
{ for i in {1..50}; do printf %s\\n '0/old/s//new/'; done; echo x;} | ex file.txt
```

Yes, it's a bit goofy.

;)

Note: This may fail if there are less than 50 instances of `old` in the file.  (I haven't tested it.)  If so, it would leave the file unmodified.

---

Better yet, use Vim.

```
vim file.txt
qqgg/old<CR>:s/old/new/<CR>q49@q
:x
```

Explanation:

```
q                                # Start recording macro
 q                               # Into register q
  gg                             # Go to start of file
    /old<CR>                     # Go to first instance of 'old'
            :s/old/new/<CR>      # Change it to 'new'
                           q     # Stop recording
                            49@q # Replay macro 49 times

:x  # Save and exit
```

Comment: :s//new<CR> should work as well, because an empty regex reuses the last used search

Answer (score 3):

A simple, but not very fast solution is to loop over commands described in 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

```
for i in $(seq 50) ; do sed -i -e "0,/oldword/s//newword/"  file.txt  ; done
```

This particular sed command probably works only for GNU sed and if *newword* is not part of *oldword*. For non-GNU sed see [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html) how to replace only the first pattern in a file.

Comment: +1 for identifying that replacing "old" with "bold" can cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk` you can set the record separator `RS` to the *word to be replaced* delimited by word boundaries. Then it is a case of setting the record separator on the output to the replacement word for the first `k` records while retaining the original record separator for the remainder

```
awk -vRS='\\ylinux\\y' -vreplacement=unix -vlimit=50 \
'{printf "%s%s", $0, NR <= limit? replacement: RT}' file
```

OR

```
awk -vRS='\\ylinux\\y' -vreplacement=unix -vlimit=50 \
'{printf "%s%s", $0, limit--? replacement: RT}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching around for an answer for this question and I see indeed, very neat solutions. In the end I used `rev`. It's another approach, that I found simpler. For example, replacing the first 2 instances of linux:

```
echo "linux linux linux" | rev | sed/linux/g2 | rev
```