# Better way to run a series of seven identical commands in sed?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

In the post [Sed - Replace first k instances of a word in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155805), a user suggests:

```
sed 's/old/new/;s/old/new/;s/old/new/;s/old/new/;s/old/new/' filename
```

as a method of replacing the first k instances of a word in a line. Seems like an inelegant solution to the problem of replacing the first k instances of old with new. There are other methods discussed, to do other things. But there are no other (or no other elegant) solutions to the problem of replacing the first k occurences of a word in a line using sed.

tl/dr:

I have a large group of items I call "slugs" that are really helpful for a variety of odd little things that I want to keep track of. They look like this:

```
#slug YYYY/MM/DD d hhmm field1 field2 field3 notes
```

And I keep them in a series of files that are dated. Then I put the files through a grep | sed | awk chain to generate reports from the data. So let's say my neighbor's dog is barking and it's keeping me up at night. Every time I hear the dog bark I will write down the time, and later I will note it in my logfile.

```
#bark 2016/04/06 W 0214 0232 Police showed up!
```

And after a while, I will have a database stored up, and hopefully, I will notice some trend, like... who knows what... the dogs bark at the full moon or something. The chain of little programs would look like:

```
grep "^#[Bb][Aa]" 2014* 2015* 2016* |\
sed 's/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/' |\
awk {something or other} >\
barking-dog-report
```

So, my problem is the sed portion:

```
sed 's/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/'
```

Which translates here into "replace the first five spaces into pipes." I use the pipe as the field separator in awk. A command like `s/ /|/5` doesn't work, that just changes the fifth space on every line into a pipe. I just think that series of sed commands looks ridiculous. It's not a global replace `s/ /|/g`, because I want to retain the spaces as spaces (and not use them as field separators) for the notes section.

Comment: Why not just use tab or `,` or `:`  or something as a field separator?  or write your "slug"s with `|` characters in place?  it's always a bad idea to use something (e.g. a space character) as a field separator when that character is also valid data within a field.  In other words, this is a problem caused by your habits, your best fix is to change your habits.

Comment: alternatively, use `sqlite` or `mysql` or `postgresql` or similar to store your notes.  and write some simple shell or `perl` or whatever scripts to add/edit/delete/query records (including output in a form directly usable by `awk` etc, such as Tab-delimited).  you could also have a web interface as well as a command-line interface.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions cas. The reason I don't write directly with the field separators is for human readability. The slugs are data points in the context of other human readable data. I would rather make the computer deal with me as a human than turn myself into a computer for the convenience of the computer :).

I am leaning toward abandoning the whole `grep | sed | awk` pipeline and doing the whole thing in ruby, with which I am somewhat comfortable. I really just find the sed one-liner to be ridiculously ungainly. Thanks, again.

Comment: `awk` can do everything `sed` (and `grep`) can, so you could rewrite the whole thing as an `awk` script with the latter's text-processing abilities.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen Kitt, I am thinking of going past awk, and keeping on to perl or ruby. I just like the historical feel of the `grep | sed | awk` toolchain for some reason. And going up to a higher level language seems like overkill. I guess I am a romantic or something.

Comment: Heh, note that `grep | sed | awk` is not as common as you might think. Usually, if you find yourself doing that, you end up moving the entire thing to `awk`. Also, @cas has a point, consider using `\t` as a field separator. That way you can still have spaces and the file is still human readable but magically also becomes computer readable.

Comment: @OswaldRoswell about your edit, did you not see the `sed 's/old/new/gK'` solution for replacing the first K instance or does that not work for you?

Comment: Tabs are as "human readable" as spaces.  If you use tab characters as the field delimiter, spaces in the notes field won't be a problem.

Comment: terdon - `sed 's/old/new/gk' replaces all 'old' with 'new' after the k-th occurrence of old. So in this instance, feeding a line like:

#book 2016/04/07 W 2300 5 Shipping News, The - E. Annie Proulx

through `sed 's/ /|/g5` will give:

#book 2016/04/07 W 2300 5 Shipping|News,|The|-|E.|Annie|Proulx

not

#book|2016/04/07|W|2300|5|Shipping News, The - E. Annie Proulx

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the five `sed` commands into one (but that doesn't make it shorter):

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6/'
```

But you can put the `grep` search into the `sed` script to reduce the shell commands by one (here with your original substitution commands):

```
sed -n '/^#[Aa][Bb]/{s/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/;s/ /|/;p;}' files |\
awk '...' > report
```

Comment: Thanks, Lucas. Something like that is especially handy if one wants to move the columns around for one reason or another. I've been all over there doesn't seem to be any other way to do this. Oh well, it's ugly, but it works!